# NSTimer Crashes Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

Why does the following crash my code?

> NSTimeInterval timeLeft = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:
>                      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
>                           objectForKey:@"lastDate"]]
>           [[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"theLabel"] 
>         text:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Remaining: %d", waitTime]]; //Set the label text

I can affirm that there is no problem with the variables.  userInfo is the dictionary that is passed in through NSTimer.

Thanks!

Comment: please format your code. that is almost unreadable and you're missing semicolons and brackets.

Comment: You are also missing the crash log, the code that sets up the timer, and any information as to how the various object references are stored;  instance variables? Globals? Localst?

Comment: This is probably what you're trying to do (assuming all the variables exist and are setup as expected): `[[timer userInfo] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Remaining: %d", waitTime] forKey:@"theLabel"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've pasted your code accurately, this line of code will definitely throw an exception:

```
[[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"theLabel"] text:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time Remaining: %d", waitTime]];
```

You're trying to call the method `-text:` on some object, which is presumably a UILabel. But there is no such method. The compiler should be warning you that it doesn't know of any selectors called `-text:`. Instead you almost certainly want `-setText:`.

You're also referencing a variable called `waitTime`, but the previous line created one called `timeLeft`. Assuming you really meant to reference `timeLeft`, you have another problem here, which is that `timeLeft` is a double but you're printing it as an integer. If you want an integral number of seconds, you should try making the format token `%.0f` and making the argument `roundf(timeLeft)`.